# Find price greater than using JSON operators

Tags: json, postgresql, postgresql-9.6

Json:

```
 "availability": [
      {
        "qty": 25,
        "price": 3599,
        "is_available": true
      },
      {
        "qty": 72,
        "price": 3599,
        },
         "is_available": true
   ]
```

If I want to find price with value = "**3599**" I use this query:

```
select * 
from product 
where to_tsvector(product.data #>> '{availability}') @@ to_tsquery('3599')
```

or this query:

```
SELECT *
FROM product 
WHERE product.data @> '{"availability": [ { "price": 3599} ] }';
```

Nice. It's work fine.

But I need also to find **price > 1000**

I try this:

```
select * 
from product 
where to_tsvector(product.data #>> '{availability}') @@ to_tsquery('>1000')
```

But the result is empty (nothing found).

Comment: That's not what full text search is intended for.

Answer (score 3):

Full text search is the wrong tool for this kind of queries.

With Postgres 12, you can use a JSON/Path expression:

```
select *
from product
where data @@ '$.availability[*].price > 100';
```

For older Postgres versions you need to unnest the array:

```
select *
from product
where exists (select *
              from jsonb_array_elements(data -> 'availability') as x(item)
              where (x.item ->> 'price')::int > 100);
```